# multiple bezierpaths masking path on view

Tags: objective-c, mask, uibezierpath

how can i draw multiple masking layers in a single view  , here is my code that i am using to do but only one masking layer is working rest of paths remove.
passing one path at a time and calling in loop it just keep last path mask remove rest of.

```
- (void)setClippingPath:(UIBezierPath *)clippingPath andView:(UIView *)view;
{
    if (![[view layer] mask])
        [[view layer] setMask:[CAShapeLayer layer]];

    [(CAShapeLayer*) [[view layer] mask] setPath:[clippingPath CGPath]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem after some research. I did following. First I declared a instance variable `UIBezierPath *resultingPath`. This variable is going to be used in your method to append the incoming paths.

```
- (void)setClippingPath:(UIBezierPath *)clippingPath andView:(UIView *)view;
    {
      if (![[view layer] mask]) {
      [[view layer] setMask:[CAShapeLayer layer]];
    }

    if (resultingPath) {
       [resultingPath appendPath:clippingPath];
       [(CAShapeLayer*) [[view layer] mask] setPath:[resultingPath CGPath]];
     }
  }
```

I tested this and it worked!

if you like tor reset the man, after some research I found this solution:

```
- (IBAction)resetMask:(id)sender {
      UIBezierPath *hole = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
      [self setClippingPath:hole andView:[self view]];
      resultingPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
  }
```

Hope it helps.